# Electrolytic cells optimum conditions

Tags: electrochemistry

I am wondering why acidified copper sulfate is used instead of regular copper sulfate solutions in electrolytic cells? What benefit does the acidified solution give?

Comment: It prevents hydrolysis of copper(II) into copper hydroxide.

Comment: Your own reasoning, based on searching, reading and analysis, is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own effort.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of $\ce{CuSO4}$ are slightly acidic. This shows that a small proportion of the ions $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ do react with water in an equilibrium : $$\ce{Cu^{2+} + H2O <=> Cu(OH)_2  +  2 H^+}$$ If some acid is added to such a solution, the equilibrium is displaced to the left-hand-side by action of mass, and no precipitate of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ appears in the solution.